# Increase local storage of xen server

Tags: citrix, xen

I have configured xen server and marathon ever run. Dell systems that we have purchased has 1200 GB hard disk. After installation of xen server, it shows 270 GB as local storage on xe server 1. How to add remaining 900 GB as local storage on xen server 1?

Answer (score 0):

If your xen server has linux installed on it , then can you check output of "cat /proc/partitions" ? This should give you the current disk partitions.

Example : In my case it is something like this :-

```
# cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0  143339962 sda
   8        1     104391 sda1
   8        2   16386300 sda2
   8        3    1052257 sda3
```

This gives you the disk name being recognized (/dev/sda) here. Further check the output of fdisk -l .

Example: In my case it is something like this :-

```
fdisk  -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 146.7 GB, 146780121600 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 17845 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/sda2              14        2053    16386300   83  Linux
/dev/sda3            2054        2184     1052257+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

This indicates i have all the space after cylinder 2184 as empty/unused.

If similar is the case , you can use fdisk and partprobe to create extended partition on the remaining unused portion of your disk and mount it on your machine (after creating filesystem on it).